# Mongoose query not deep populating fully

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following query:

```
const comments = await Comment.findById("comment1").populate({
  path: "replies",
  populate: [
    {
      path: "replies"
    }
  ]
});
```

This query yields the following JSON response:

```
{
    "parentCommentId": null,
    "_id": "comment1",
    "user": "user1",
    "text": "OP",
    "post": "post1",
    "replies": [
        {
            "parentCommentId": "comment1",
            "replyCount": 1,
            "_id": "comment2",
            "user": "user2",
            "text": "reply",
            "post": "post1",
            "replies": [
                {
                    "parentCommentId": "comment2",
                    "_id": "comment3",
                    "user": "user3",
                    "text": "reply to a reply",
                    "post": "post1",
                    "replies": [
                        "5d7757a2e6835f6d98ce723f" // <--- this is not populated
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason, it is only populating the `Comment` document down two levels only, but I need it to go down all the way until the length of `replies` will be 0.

My schema:

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    parentCommentId: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    replyCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user"
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "post"
    },
    replies: [
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: as you want deep populate, and there is no inbuilt function for this i guess. you might want to take look at here: https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate ,

Comment: That's very inconvenient.. how is this not possible?